# Transitioning "Visibility" in blend using visual states

Tags: c#, wpf, blend, visualstates

So I have a loading control which if effectively a usercontrol that says "Loading" over the top of my main user control, preventing the user interacting with my program until it is loaded.

I would like to use visual states to transition the visibility of the "Loading" control to slowly fade to collapsed and stay collapsed for any other state within my program.

I currently have my loading control:

```
    <ContentControl x:Name="contentControl" Content="{StaticResource loadingAnimation}">
        <i:Interaction.Triggers>
            <ei:DataTrigger Value="false" Binding="{Binding IsLoadingAnimationVisible}">
                <ei:GoToStateAction StateName="Loaded"/>
            </ei:DataTrigger>
        </i:Interaction.Triggers>
    </ContentControl>
```

Where:

```
    <VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
        <VisualStateGroup x:Name="VisualStateGroup">
            <VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" To="Collapsed">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" To="Expanded">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
                <VisualTransition GeneratedDuration="0:0:0.5" To="Loaded">
                    <VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                        <CubicEase EasingMode="EaseInOut"/>
                    </VisualTransition.GeneratedEasingFunction>
                </VisualTransition>
            </VisualStateGroup.Transitions>
            <VisualState x:Name="Expanded">
                <Storyboard>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="metaGrid">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl">
                        <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
                    </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
            <VisualState x:Name="Loaded">
                <Storyboard>
                    <BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.IsHitTestVisible)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl">
                        <DiscreteBooleanKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="False"/>
                    </BooleanAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Opacity)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl">
                        <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
                    </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                </Storyboard>
            </VisualState>
        </VisualStateGroup>
    </VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups>
```

now the problem with this is that when I trigger the Expanded and Collapsed states the "Loading" contentControl becomes visible and then fades to collapsed over .5 seconds.
How can I permanently set the loading control to collapsed once the Loaded state has been triggered?

**EDIT**

I am not sure this is the correct way to transition a visibility in blend (i.e. setting ishittestvisible = false and opacitiy = 0 but it was the only way I could think as setting visibility.collapsed didnt seem to transition when I tried it, it would snap to collapsed)

Comment: How do you expect *to slowly fade to* a discrete `Visibility` value, like `Collapsed`? It is a discrete value, so either it is `Collapsed`, or it is not.

Comment: I use the word Visiblity in the English sense not the C# sense.. For example an element with Visibility.Visible but Height = 0 is not "Visible"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It sounds like you want to use the [`Timeline.BeginTime` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.timeline.begintime(v=vs.110).aspx). Using this property, you can delay the start of the `Visibility.Collapsed Animation`. Ideally, you should set the `Duration` property on your `DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames` object too. Try this:

```
<VisualState x:Name="Collapsed">
    <Storyboard>
        <DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames Duration="0:0:5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(FrameworkElement.Width)" Storyboard.TargetName="metaGrid">
            <EasingDoubleKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="0"/>
        </DoubleAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames BeginTime="0:0:5" Storyboard.TargetProperty="(UIElement.Visibility)" Storyboard.TargetName="contentControl">
            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0" Value="{x:Static Visibility.Collapsed}"/>
        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
    </Storyboard>
</VisualState>
```